# P/Invoking to Native DLL with Runtime Filename

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

For versioning reasons it would be beneficial for me to be able to use p/invoke on a native C++ dll whose filename will be determined at runtime, as such:

```
[DllImport(myDllFilename)]
private static extern void MyInvokedMethod();
```

Unfortunately `[DllImport]` is an attribute and demands a constant expression. Are there any other options for getting around this error?

I am aware I can use identically named files in different folders and load the right one at runtime, but being able to use differently named files would be ideal for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need to PInvoke several things (`LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` - see links below)... it is called "late binding native code"... using this is not easy/recommended but it is possible...

Some relevant links with explanations, samples and source code:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/14/181932.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dyninvok.aspx
- http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPRocAddress.html
- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.loadlibrary

Comment: Thanks for all the links. As you & David mentioned this seems like more trouble than it's worth, but I am glad to have learned a new technique which will no doubt come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 3):

There is no workaround. You will need to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. That's really no fun at all so I'd try to avoid going that way if feasible.

Comment: Thank you. A high fun factor is critical so this might be decided against. :)

Comment: Too bad the [`AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event doesn't fire for pinvoke.  I found [a feature requests on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/293742/pinvoke-needs-appdomain-assemblyresolve-equivalent).